# c# SharpDX ScaleEffect Interpolation question

Tags: c#, directx, direct2d, sharpdx

i've been using this wonderful library for low impact screen recording software however im at a point where i need to use a DirectX Scale Effect to scale the image down with anisotropic filtering.

I can create the effect just fine and set up most of its parameters, however im not able to set the most important one for me `scaleEffect.SetValue((int)ScaleProperties.InterpolationMode, (int)SharpDX.Direct2D1.ScaleInterpolationMode.Anisotropic);`

As soon as the program runs it crashes at that line with an invalid parameter exception.
I've searched and couldnt find anything wrong with the code, but then again i have almost 0 experience with anything Direct2D.

Here is the full code for that specific effect for reference:

```
SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effect scaleEffect = new D2D.Effect(textureDc, D2D.Effect.Scale);
scaleEffect.Cached = true;
scaleEffect.SetInput(0, frameBitmap, false);
var centerPoint = new SharpDX.Vector2(0, 0);
var newSize = new SharpDX.Vector2(0.2f, 0.2f);
scaleEffect.SetValue((int)ScaleProperties.CenterPoint, centerPoint);
scaleEffect.SetValue((int)ScaleProperties.Scale, newSize);

//Crashes Here: scaleEffect.SetValue((int)ScaleProperties.InterpolationMode, (int)SharpDX.Direct2D1.ScaleInterpolationMode.Anisotropic);
Error Message: SharpDX.SharpDXException: 'HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: The parameter is incorrect.'

textureDc.BeginDraw();
textureDc.DrawImage(scaleEffect, InterpolationMode.Anisotropic);
textureDc.EndDraw();
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

UPDATE:

As per @Simon Mourier comment, the solution to avoid this bug somewhere in the SharpDX API, is to use the SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.Scale instead.
This way, i can confirm the InterpolationMode does no longer crash and works as intended!

Here is the new, working code for anyone running into the same issue.

```
SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.Scale scaleClass = new D2D.Effects.Scale(textureDc);
scaleClass.SetInput(0, frameBitmap,false);
scaleClass.Cached = true;
var centerPoint = new SharpDX.Vector2(0, 0);
var newSize = new SharpDX.Vector2(0.2f, 0.2f);
scaleClass.CenterPoint = centerPoint;
scaleClass.ScaleAmount = newSize;
scaleClass.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Anisotropic;
textureDc.BeginDraw();
textureDc.DrawImage(scaleClass);
textureDc.EndDraw();
```

PS: For anyone wondering about casting the value to uint instead using the first method, it returns the following error:
(Argument1 cannot convert from uint to int)
So it semms that there might be some underlying bug in this specific scenario.

Comment: The code seems globally ok. Have you tried to use the SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.Scale class directly (https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct2D1/Effects/Scale.cs)? Or have you tried to cast the enum value as uint instead of int?

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first solution works flawlessly.

I've just posted it in OP with a code example, if you want to post an answear with the code, please go ahead and copy it from there so i can accept it as the solution as im perfectly happy with your workaround.

PS: From anyone wondering about casting the value to uint instead, it returns the following error (Argument1 cannot convert from uint to int) so it semms that there might be some underlying bug in this specific casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the [SharpDX.Direct2D1.Effects.Scale](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct2D1/Effects/Scale.cs) directly which is a wrapper over the `Effect` class and comes with an `InterpolationMode` property.